# any {addslashes} function in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am working in a symfony app and I need to use a function like the addslashes function in php but I can't find any think like that in twig ? is there any way to do that

Comment: Unless you add the `raw` filter and a few exceptions, Twig escapes the output by default. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am traying to add the antislash befor any single cuote in my string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register PHP's `addslashes` function as a Twig filter by doing:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('addslashes', 'addslashes'));
```

and then in your twig template use it by doing: `{{ var|addslashes }}`.

If auto-escaping is enabled, then your filter will be escaped after it is called. If auto-escaping is causing you problems, then take a look at the "automatic-escaping" link below and see how to disable it. It should go without saying--but, if you disable auto-escaping, then you are responsible for sanitizing the data before it is output.

Resources:

1. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#automatic-escaping
2. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters

Answer (score 6):

Here is the answer

If you are trying to addslashes in HTML code then try

```
 {{ my_variable|e('html') }}
```

If you are trying to addslashes in JS code then try

```
 {{ my_variable|e('js') }}
```

If answers works for you then vote the answer.

Comment: This was the best answer for me.  I was looking for addslashes for use with javascript.  Worked a treat and simpler than the other answer. (The other answer is the most correct answer to the specific original question though!)